# How can i reassemble the following json using map function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to make a json format from a given json

I use map function in nodejs but it dosen't work right. I give all the details here. I want a code that will give me that required json format.

Given Json :

```
var x =
[
[
    {
        "title":"My feel about shape up",
        "answer":"neutral",
        "objectives":[
            "Awareness"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"How good is shape up ?",
        "answer":"a",
        "objectives":[
            "Awareness"
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "title":"My feel about shape up",
        "answer":"neutral",
        "objectives":[
            "Awareness"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"How good is shape up ?",
        "answer":"Awareness",
        "objectives":[
            "Awareness"
        ]
    }
]
];
```

Code i tried :

```
result = x.map(function(subarray) {
var data  = subarray.map(v =>{
  const wd= {[v.title ]: v.answer}
   return wd;
   })
   return data;
```

})

Actual output :

```
[ [ { 'My feel about shape up': 'neutral' },
{ 'How good is shape up ?': 'a' } ],
[ { 'My feel about shape up': 'neutral' },
{ 'How good is shape up ?': 'Awareness' } ] ]
```

Expected output :

```
[ 
{ 'My feel about shape up': 'neutral',
'How good is shape up ?': 'a' } ,
{ 'My feel about shape up': 'neutral',
'How good is shape up ?': 'Awareness' } 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning an array from inside loop instead you need to create an object to get desired result,

```js
let data = [[{"title":"My feel about shape up","answer":"neutral","objectives":["Awareness"]},{"title":"How good is shape up ?","answer":"a","objectives":["Awareness"]}],[{"title":"My feel about shape up","answer":"neutral","objectives":["Awareness"]},{"title":"How good is shape up ?","answer":"Awareness","objectives":["Awareness"]}]];

let final = data.map(value =>
  value.reduce((op, {title, answer}) => {
    op[title] = answer
    return op
  },{})
)
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [[
    {"title":"My feel about shape up", "answer":"neutral", "objectives":[ "Awareness"]},
    {"title":"How good is shape up ?", "answer":"a", "objectives":[ "Awareness"]}
], [
    {"title":"My feel about shape up", "answer":"neutral", "objectives":["Awareness"]},
    {"title":"How good is shape up ?", "answer":"Awareness", "objectives":["Awareness"]}
]];

const result = data.map(
    arr => arr.reduce((r, {title: k, answer: v}) => (r[k] = v, r), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reduce` for the subarrays to get one object for each subarray;

```js
var x = [[{"title":"My feel about shape up","answer":"neutral","objectives":["Awareness"]},{"title":"How good is shape up ?","answer":"a","objectives":["Awareness"]}],[{"title":"My feel about shape up","answer":"neutral","objectives":["Awareness"]},{"title":"How good is shape up ?","answer":"Awareness","objectives":["Awareness"]}]];
const res = x.map(e => e.reduce((acc, { title, answer }) => ({ ...acc, [title]: answer }), {}));
console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var x = [[{"title":"My feel about shape up","answer":"neutral","objectives":["Awareness"]},{"title":"How good is shape up ?","answer":"a","objectives":["Awareness"]}],[{"title":"My feel about shape up","answer":"neutral","objectives":["Awareness"]},{"title":"How good is shape up ?","answer":"Awareness","objectives":["Awareness"]}]];
var res = x.map(function(e) {
  return e.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    return Object.assign({}, acc, { [curr.title]: curr.answer });
  }, {});
});
console.log(res);
```